# How can I "Collapse All" Nodes in TGUITestRunner?

Tags: delphi, dunit

DUnit offers a context menu item "Expand all" and "Hide Test Nodes". In my test projects however, choosing the latter option still leaves very many test suite hierarchy nodes open. Only the test nodes on the last level are hidden. Is there a secret key which collapses all nodes, or all but the highest level?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing built in already that can be enabled with a "secret key" or suchlike.

You have to modify the DUnit source to achieve this. Look in `GUITestRunner` and add an item to the `pmTestTree` popup menu which calls `TestTree.FullCollapse`.

Comment: @mjn Was this helpful to you?